# Multiple requests hitting the database – wait until cache is available

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, caching, asp.net-web-api

We are using a simple `Memory Cache` to cache the response of an intense query that otherwise is being hit multiple times a second. The cache is pretty fast, the offset is set at 2 seconds.

```
public StateService
{
    private readonly ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    private const string _queueStatesCacheKey = "_states";

    public IList<States> GetStates()
    {
        var states = _cache.Get(_statesCacheKey);
                if (states== null)
                {
                    states = getStatesFromDatabase();
                    _cache.Set(_statesCacheKey, states, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(Settings.AppSettings.QueueStateCacheExpiration));
                }
       return states as List<States>;
    }
}
```

The method: `getStatesFromDatabase()` simply runs a `SQL-query` to run a stored procedure and fetch those values.

This is all fetched via an `API` and currently we're experiencing conditions were the cache is cleared and `getStatesFromDatabase()` is being hit by 4-5 threads at the same time.

- Could I wrap `GetStates()` in `Task` and wait until it's completed for another request starts a new Task?
- Or do I have to make it a singleton service for that to work?
- Or do I have to make a new sort of provider that deals with returning the `List<States>`?
- Is it better to cache it differently or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SemaphoreSlim` to lock other threads until cache is ready:

```
public StateService
{
    private readonly ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    private const string _queueStatesCacheKey = "_states";
    private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public IList<States> GetStates()
    {
        var states = _cache.Get(_statesCacheKey);
        if (states== null)
        {
           try
           {
              semaphore.Wait();
              // we check again from cache, that could have been populated from other thread
              states = _cache.Get(_statesCacheKey);
              if(states != null) return states as IList<States>;
              states = getStatesFromDatabase();
              _cache.Set(_statesCacheKey, states, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(Settings.AppSettings.QueueStateCacheExpiration));
           }
           finally
           {
              semaphore.Release();
           }
        }
        return states as List<States>;
    }
}
```

You can configure no timeout (like in the example) or some sort of timeout, maybe based on running time statistics for your query.

Please note that this will work only in a single server & single process setup. If your application is meant to run on multiple servers or multiple processes, this solution will allow one concurrent query per server/process.

To avoid this you'll want to check some package for managing the lock externally (distributed locking). Nuget package [DistributedLock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DistributedLock) is one that do the job, for instance.

Comment: Didn't know about Semaphore - looks to be exactly what I need.
The server is clustered but the load balancer currently only hits one server so this will do fine for now. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok. If the query runs relatively quick (0.x seconds) and doesn't make the DB to suffer, I think you can let this solution in a clustered environment too... otherwise, distributed locking **and** distributed caching are really recommended.

Comment: Small note is that I had to do "new SemaphoreSlim(1)" - otherwise it wouldn't continue past the "Wait()" function.

Comment: @HenrikM You're actually right, sir! :) I forget *every time* to change `0 => 1` when copying from docs (facepalm). Fixing the answer immediately, thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping `GetStates()` in `Task` and waiting for it will not fix any problems, As you are using asp.net application each user request is received in new `Thread`. It's not a good idea for one request to wait for another request to fetch something before returning data. As i see implementing your approach, you will have to lock method or maintain list of already running tasks in some Singleton, you will have to worry on thread-safety, Task cancellation and so on. It will complicate more things than solve.

What you have is actually good implementation if your `GetStates()` is not called often.
Alternative solution would be to maintain list in memory, always return that list and update it by polling database every x seconds. This ways it does not matter how many users come, there is always only single thread who is retrieving data from database.

Basically if you have a case where no-one is querying your service for some time, then your approach is good, if your service is busy enough, polling in every x seconds and always returning list would be better.